# In Python, is it possible to let a subprocess write to an in-memory bytes object instead of a file?

Tags: python

I have a process that I want to run, which does conversion of files into pdfs. I'm using Libreoffice for that. I call Libreoffice as a subprocess, from Python. Libreoffice then writes to a new file on my system. This is of course totally independent of my Python program. After the conversion I will read the file and then use this file for something else, in Python.

But is it at all possible to capture this file as a bytes object in Python instead of a file? This would eliminate the need for reading the file after the conversion, and just keeping it in memory.

Comment: If the "subprocess" is writing to a file, at that point you don't really have control over it. If you can change the code of the subprocess, sure. If not, then the solution you have is just fine.

Comment: Isn't possible to convert the files using some library in python? If true, its easy to emulate file descriptor with BytesIO